# Checking if undefined and null in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary-operator

I'm a bit confused when checking if null or undefined and if I should be using `!==` or `!=` and "undefined" or undefined.

Here is some code I'm working on. Where am I going wrong with my null/unudefined etc?

```
var c = (jQuery(this).prop("target") != null && jQuery(this).prop("target") != undefined && jQuery(this).prop("target").toLowerCase() == "_blank") ? 1 : 0;
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: Do you absolutely _have to_ call `toLowerCase()`?

Comment: @AshReva Not with this exactly, but as part of trying to hunt out the error I'm checking things like this I'm not 100% on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Both `null` and `undefined` are "falsy" values, thus they can be checked like they were boolean values. Thus, there's no sense comparing to `null` and `undefined` except for certain situations where you need to know if they are such values.
- when comparing, it's best to use strict comparison (like `===`,`!==` and so on)
- the `&&` in a condition does not evaluate the following condition if the one preceeding it is "falsy".
- [You don't even need jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Pq9RB/) since `this` is your DOM object (presumably an `<a>`) and you are trying to get the `target` property:

In the end:

```
var c = (this.target && this.target.toLowerCase() === "_blank") ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: just to clarify, it is not always best to use the 'falsy' properties of null and undefined. This is because values such as zero and empty string are also considered falsy but likely in many instances allowable values. So if you are in a situation were null and undefined values are not allowed, but zero and empty string (and the other falsy values) are allowed, you need to explicitly check for null and undefined.

Answer (score 14):

In general, keep it simple.

To check for `undefined`, use:

```
foo === undefined
foo !== undefined
```

---

To check for `null`, use:

```
foo === null
foo !== null
```

---

To check for either at the same time, use:

```
foo == null
foo != null
```

---

And in any case, store your `.prop()` to a variable to keep it clean. But in your case, if it equals `"_blank"`, then you know it isn't `null` or `undefined`, so:

```
var targ = jQuery(this).prop("target").toLowerCase();

var c = targ === "_blank" ? 1 : 0;
```

---

Or you could make it even shorter by coercing the `boolean` to a `number`:

```
var targ = jQuery(this).prop("target").toLowerCase();

var c = +(targ === "_blank");
```

---

These last two solutions are safe because `.prop()` will always return a `string`.

Comment: @acowley: You're welcome. And don't worry about people that tell you to do funny stuff like `typeof foo === "undefined"`. That's a confusing, bug prone and unnecessary syntax. Just don't ever create a variable named `undefined`, and you'll be ok.

Comment: No Sir. I was thinking of heading down the `typeof` path before asking here. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to checking undefined:

```
if(typeof variable_here != 'undefined'){
   // your code here.
 };
```

And this is the best way to checking null:

```
if(variable_here !== null){
       // your code here.
     };
```

So your code should be like this:

```
var c = (jQuery(this).prop("target") !== null && typeof jQuery(this).prop("target") !== 'undefined' && jQuery(this).prop("target").toLowerCase() == "_blank") ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since undefined would be the variable type, use `typeof`

```
var c = (
 $(this).attr("target") != NULL && 
 typeof $(this).attr("target") != "undefined" && 
 $(this).attr("target").toLowerCase() == "_blank"
) ? 1 : 0;
```

I think, however, that you only need the last check. Is target `"_blank"`, `c` needs to be `1`, otherwise, `0`. Does it really matter if `target` is even set?

Also, use the [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) methode to get attributes, since `prop()` if for properties like `selectedIndex` or `tagName`.

Comment: I think the OP is checking the validity of the "target" property so that they can call the `toLowerCase` method on it, otherwise the other two checks are pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get the same property 3 times just to check a value.

```
var c = 0;
var prop = $(this).prop("target");
if(prop && prop.toLowerCase() === "_blank") c = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got something like this which is not relevent to your question but will help you

```
var targ = jQuery(this).prop("target").toLowerCase();
```

now if you want to check whether targ is null or undefined

```
 var c = (!targ || "") ? 1 : 0
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you are not required to explicitly check if a variable is null or undefined because:

1. null or undefined return false in a boolean expression.
2. JS expressions are evaluated from left to right. So for a || b, if a is false, then only b will be evaluated. But if a is true, b will not be checked. Similarly for a && b if a is false, b will not be evaluated.

Hence, if (a != null) { "do something" } can be written as if (a) { "do something" } or simply a && "do something".

In the same way, it can be used to set a default value when the value is set to null or undefined:

```
function someFunction(age){
    var age= age|| 18;
}
```

Reference : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/472/usage-of-the-ternary-operator-with-functions-listening-to-click-events